# Preg_replace adding second parameter to php function

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm still totally lost when it comes to preg_replace function so I would be very happy if someone helped me with this one.

I have string which can contain a call to function like: `Published("today")`and I need to convert it through regular expression to `Published("today", 1)`

I basically need to add a second parameter to the function via regular expression.
I cant use str_replace because the first parameter can be (has to be) alphanumeric text.

Comment: try something like this:       $foo = preg_replace('Published\("today"\)', 'Published\("today", 1\)');

Comment: Hi, the thing is I cant do that, because the "Today" parameters is just for show, it can be anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'Published("today")';
$foo = preg_replace('/Published\("(\w+)"\)/', 'Published("$1", 1)', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks man, however it still showing an error : Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash, I have encountered this several times and didnt figure it out.. Can you adjust this very please?

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) should do the job I reckon.

```
<?php
$string = 'Published("today"); Published("yesterday"); Published("5 days ago");';

$callback = function($match) {
    return sprintf('%s, 1', $match[0]);
};

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=Published\()"[^"]+"(?=\))~',
    $callback,
    $string
);

echo $string;

/*
    Published("today", 1); Published("yesterday", 1); Published("5 days ago", 1);
*/
```